# VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP combo

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup, lookup

I am struggling with the following (see snapshot) and I can't understand what I'm missing.

If the id matches, I would like to extract the value of that id in when the values in col2 matches the headers in table2. So for 348, I would expect the value in coverage to be 0.

[image]

I would like to achieve the same as in this source:
https://www.automateexcel.com/formulas/vlookup-hlookup-combined/

A snapshot of the source example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the example you link to, your `Table1` doesn't have the line **Column #, 2, 3, 4** - that's where `HLOOKUP()` does the trick. However, you can also [**search the value in the table**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-value-from-a-rectangular-table/1029?u=johnsun) without this helper row:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$D$5;MATCH($F3;$A$2:$A$5;0);MATCH($I3;$A$2:$D$2;0));"???")`

or

`=IFERROR(OFFSET($A$2;MATCH($F3;$A$3:$A$5;0);MATCH($I3;$B$2:$D$2;0));"")`

Comment: hi! Thanks for your answer. However, this only works to extract values related to A and gives unwanted zeroes. I just want 1 and 0 when the id matches. I would like to obtain the output using vlookup and hlookup.

Comment: I've edited the question in case it helps.

Comment: @Joehat Oh yes, now your question is much clearer (I changed my answer)